# Why did my Perl sort program fail?

Tags: perl, sorting

I had an assignemt for a Perl program that would take strings at the command line, and print them back sorted, and reverse sorted with a -r or --reverse command switch.  The sort part worked, but when I envoked the -r it would drop one of the strings.

perl Bagwell_Assign_One.plx -r c b a

b a

```
# Sort and Unsort
#Zak Bagwell
#The purpose of this program is to take strings as command line arguments and sort
#invoke by: perl filename.plx string string string 
# -r will output reverse order sort


use 5.8.8;
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;  # use for the -r reverse sort
use vars qw($opt_r);  # use for the -r reverse sort
use vars qw($opt_reverse); # use for the -reverse sort

getopts('r:');  # use for the -r reverse sort


if ($#ARGV < 1) {  # a test for strings is preformed first
  print "Invalid command line arguments to program. Please supply two or more strings to sort.\n";
  die  "\n";
  } #end if


elsif (defined $opt_r){ # if -r is present, the sort is reversed 

  @ARGV = reverse sort(@ARGV);
  }

elsif (defined $opt_reverse){ # if -reverse is present, the sort is reversed  

  @ARGV = reverse sort(@ARGV);
  }


else {  # if no -r, then normal sort
  @ARGV = sort @ARGV;
  } #end else


# Display output 
print "@ARGV\n";
```

So, what did I do wrong?  My prof gave me almost no feedback...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below colon tells [`Getopt::Std`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) that the `-r` flag takes an argument:

```
getopts('r:');                # use for the -r reverse sort
```

To fix, simply remove the colon:

```
getopts('r');                # use for the -r reverse sort
```

For additional simplification, I would recommend just using [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) instead for all such projects.

It automatically handles abbreviations of long option names.  So `-r` can be used as an alias for `--reverse` as long as there aren't any other options that begin with the letter R.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions(
    "reverse" => \( my $opt_reverse ),
) or die "Error in command line arguments\n";

die "Invalid command line arguments to program. Please supply two or more strings to sort.\n"
    if @ARGV < 2;

@ARGV = sort @ARGV;
@ARGV = reverse @ARGV if $opt_reverse;

print "@ARGV\n";
```

Comment: You can make it explicit that `-r` is an alias for `--reverse` by using `"reverse|r"`